# stop case sensitive sorting array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

How to sort without case sensitive sorting in array javascript or typescript.

like the input is `[/,2,$,3,B,a,A]`

output should be

```
[$,/,2,3,A,a,B]
```

Comment: Are `2` and `3` numbers or strings? And why is `A` before `a` in the result if `a` is before `A` in the unsorted array?

Comment: @MrGeek: All values are strings. I want alphabetic order following with uppercase letter like A,a,B

Comment: In this case, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [String.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with `numeric: true` and `caseFirst: "upper"` options for the alpha-numeric. For the symbols case you can match on a regular expression and use `charCodeAt` for the sorting:

```js
let data = ['/', '2', '$', '3', 'B', 'a', 'A']
let regEx = new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]/)

let result = data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (regEx.test(a) && regEx.test(b))
    return a.charCodeAt(0) - b.charCodeAt(0)
  else
    return a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { numeric: true, caseFirst: 'upper'})
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thank you but hard code fix is not suggestible, Value could be any symbmol.

Comment: Updated with a better RegEx which matches on non-alphanumeric so you can match on `charCodeAt` instead of the localeCompare etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: sorry, not working this scenario, ["/", "2", "$", "3", "British", "a", "Asia"]. Only for single letter sorting is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```js
alert(['/','2','$','3','B','a','A'].sort(Intl.Collator().compare));
```

check this example for it's quite the same as your output but some modification required.

Comment: I'm looking for normal sorting  for the all values except alphabetic with the order A,a,B

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```js
var arr = ["/", "2", "$", "3", "B", "a", "A"];

var sorted = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var g = /^[A-Z]$/i;
  if (!g.test(a) || !g.test(b)) return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
  var r = a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
  return r ? r : b.localeCompare(a);
});

console.log(...sorted); // => $ / 2 3 A a B
```

Comment: $ should come first as default behavior of array sorting

Comment: @klmuralimohan Why should `$` come first? It's not first in the original array!

Comment: @klmuralimohan Well now `$` comes first, but it's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: thanks for the quick update but I'm not looking for hard code fix for "$". It should sort like how array.sort() works except alphabetic order.

Comment: @klmuralimohan It should now sort just like `Array.sort()` except for alphabetic order.

Comment: :Thanks for the quick solution. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: sorry, not working this scenario,  ["/", "2", "$", "3", "British", "a", "Asia"]; Only for single letter sorting is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you. It sorts according to default `.sort()` order, except for alphabets, where `A` comes before `a` which comes before `B`:

```js
let arr = ['/','2','$','3','B','a','A']; 

arr.sort((a,b) => {

    let match = /\w/;
    //if it's an alphabet, we sort according to uppercase first
    if (match.test(a) && match.test(b)) {
        return a.localeCompare(b, "en", {caseFirst:"upper"});
    }
    // for all other symbols and numbers, we follow default .sort order
    else {
        let test = [a,b].sort();
        return (test[0] === a)?-1:1;
    }
});

console.log(arr); //['$', '/', 2, 3, 'A', 'a', 'B']
```